# How can I implement custom partitioning logic in Cassandra?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql, partitioning, sharding

I'm new to Cassandra and I am building a Chat Application. Assuming I have to store the chat messages in a DB, I expect to use Cassandra, since it allows fast writes. My data model for the "Messages" table is the following :-

message_id 
from_user_id 
to_user_id 
channel_id 
message_text

Now, I want to shard this in a way so that chat history for a particular channel (1:1 or Group chat) is accessible from a single shard. As such, ideally, I would like to shard the DB based on channel_id. Here are the challenges I have:-

1. I cannot make "channel_id" the partition key since it can have duplicates (one channel can have multiple messages) and Cassandra doesn't allow duplicates if partition key is made up of only one column.
2. I can use "channel_id+message_id" as the partition key, which will be unique, but then Cassandra will hash the combination of channel_id+message_id and can place messages from the same channel on different shards. So I have to do scatter gather again.

Here are my questions :-

1. Is there a way to override Cassandra's (or any non-relational DB) partitioning/sharding logic? Can I write my own partitioning logic so as to determine the shard I want to write to in my application logic? I know Redis allows client side partitioning (See [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/redis-sharding.html#sharding_(partitioning)_implementations)). Does Cassandra allow something like this too?
2. General Question - Usually, when when designing systems, we try to shard our data so as to minimize the chances of scatter gather for the most frequent queries. If Cassandra (and other non-relational DBs) don't allow duplicates in partition keys, how else can we achieve such a design? (*Please note that using multiple columns as partition key doesn't help because Cassandra will hash the combination of those column values and will place them on different shards, as presented in the example above*).

Could someone help me understand how best to model this? And please correct me if my understanding is wrong. (*As mentioned I'm new to Cassandra and non-relational DBs in general*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cassandra partitioning

---

In Cassandra, table's **primary key** is made of **two parts**: a **partition key** (which can be a simple key made of one column or a compound key made of multiple columns) and **optional clustering keys** (aka sort keys).

The *partition key* is responsible for *data distribution* across your nodes, i.e. determines the "shard".

The *clustering key* is responsible for *data sorting* within the partition.

Example:

```
 create table example (
  col_A text,
  col_B text,
  col_C text,
  col_D text,
  col_E text,
  col_F text,
  PRIMARY KEY((col_A, col_B), col_C, col_D)      
);
```

In this example, values of *col_A* and *col_B* determine the partition, while *col_C* and *col_D* are still part of the primary key, but only define the order of data within that partition.

In your case, you can have *channel_id* as the *partition key*, and then *message_id* as *clustering key* that would sort records within that that partition (shard).

A table might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  channel_id text,
  message_id text,
  from_user_id text,
  message_text text,
  to_user_id text,
  PRIMARY KEY (channel_id, message_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (message_id ASC)
```

Example data:

```
select * from messages;

 channel_id | message_id | from_user_id | message_text | to_user_id
------------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------
          1 |        m-1 |          u-1 |          foo |        u-2
          1 |        m-2 |          u-2 |          bar |        u-1
          2 |        m-1 |         u-11 |      foo bar |       u-10
          2 |       m-10 |         u-10 |          bar |       u-11
          2 |       m-11 |         u-11 |          foo |       u-10

select * from messages where channel_id = '1';

 channel_id | message_id | from_user_id | message_text | to_user_id
------------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------
          1 |        m-1 |          u-1 |          foo |        u-2
          1 |        m-2 |          u-2 |          bar |        u-1
```

2. Custom partitioning

---

The thing that determines data placement on the server side based on partition key values is called a *partitioner* and is configurable in the *cassandra.yaml* file on the server.

Basically, a partitioner is a function for deriving a token representing a row from its partition key, typically by hashing. Each row of data is then distributed across the cluster by the value of the token.

Cassandra offers the following partitioners that can be set in the cassandra.yaml file.

- Murmur3Partitioner (default): uniformly distributes data across the cluster based on MurmurHash hash values.
- RandomPartitioner: uniformly distributes data across the cluster based on MD5 hash values.
- ByteOrderedPartitioner: keeps an ordered distribution of data lexically by key bytes

You can read more about partitioners here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/architecture/archPartitionerAbout.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So basically you're saying :-


1. Partition Key indeed "can have duplicates" (because channel_id can have duplicates, i.e. multiple messages in the same channel)


2. Primary Key (combination of channel_id and message_id) needs to be unique. 



My understanding was that #1 was not possible. Could you please confirm?



(I have been trying to verify that but I'm using Datastax Astra and all my data keeps ending up in the same partition).

Comment: I can confirm. Within the same partition (i.e. unique partition key value) you can store multiple rows and every one of them will be identifiable by complete primary key (i.e. partition key values + clustering key values).